# Spring Thymeleaf Jquery link syntax error

Tags: jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I try to work with Spring 4 (4.0.2), Thymeleaf 2 (2.1.3) and JQuery 2 (2.1.1). All I've tried is to make navigation pills using Petclinic example, however I've got JQuery syntax error on Thymeleaf's URL syntax

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /petclinic/register.html
```

My header page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head th:fragment="headTag">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Page title</title>

 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="../../../resources/css/main.css" th:href="@{/resources/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script sr="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and body page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body th:fragment="bodyHeader">
<img th:src="@{/resources/images/banner-graphic.png}" src="../../../resources/images/banner-graphic.png" class="center"/>

<div class="center" style="width: 601px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="../welcome.html" th:href="@{/}" data-toggle="pill">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../register.html" th:href="@{/register.html}" data-toggle="pill">Register</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got the error on Firebug's console, when landing on home page and trying to enter Register navigation pill, it tells that problem is Thymeleaf's expression: @{/register.html}

Comment: Can you post more information on the error you are getting?

Comment: Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
 throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};         1436 line in JQuery 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading the page in the browser?  Is it hosted in a web container like Tomcat?  When you see the page source in the browser, how do the URLs appear?  Do they appear as `/...` or `@{/...}`?

If the URLs appear as `@{/...}` in the page source, the prefix `th` is not being picked up by the renderer.  Change `<html lang="en">` to `<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` and try again.

Comment: I've already downgraded JQuery to the version that's used in the examples